# Collision resolution between two fast moving circles. One that doesnt react to collisions

Tags: math, physics, collision

Alright, so I have dove in and understood how to do collisions between fast moving circles and basic curve/line based shapes. I have not yet wrapped my head around detecting the collisions between two moving circles. I have been modeling them as capsules and so while I could find their intersection points easily I am not sure how to resolve where one stopped and the other began.

Furthermore once I know that information I really don't know how to resolve their velocities and positions.

The situation is that there are acouple hundred little circles, quickly moving following the laws of physics. There are also much more massive circles that follow the position of the mouse/finger/touch as it moves and inherit the fingers velocity etc. The goal is that the little circles are hit off of the larger circles. This is tricky because the large circles wont react to the collision at all and most algorithms I can find require that.

How do I even begin to think about and resolve this type of collision scenario? Not only can I not figure out where the fast moving little circle collided with the fast moving large circle I have no idea how to factor in the finger velocity to properly collide the little circles off of it.

Any good ideas?

Comment: How fast is fast? It sounds very similar to [what I did a couple of years ago](https://nicoschertler.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/elastic-collision-of-circles-and-spheres/). You might want to take a look.

Comment: So the little circles will move no more than the large circles radius each frame. The fingers can move as fast as fingers do. That is a very well written article and that *just* might be it. Will follow back if not.

Answer (score 1):

Let `x1`, `y1`, `vx1`, `vy1` be x-position, y-position, x-velocity, and y-velocity of `circle1`. Similarly, we have `x2`, `y2`, `vx2`, `vy2` for `circle2`.

Since one of the circle, say `circle1`, does not react to collision, it is useful to look at the collision from the perspective of this big guy (also called frame of reference). In this frame of reference, `circle2` has the x-velocity of `vx2 - vx1` and y-velocity of `vy2 - vy1`. The x- and y-position of `circle2` is similarly `x2 - x1` and `y2 - y1`.

In this frame of reference also, `circle1` is not moving and can be treated as a static wall.

You can then treat this problem similar to that of a moving `circle2` colliding against a wall at a normal vector of `(x2-x1 , y2-y1)` and velocity of `(vx2-vx1 , vy2-vy1)`.

I'm assuming you know how to solve this, since you said you understood collisions between a circle and a shape.

Once you get the final velocity of `circle2`, just remember to go back to the original perspective by adding `vx1` to the x-velocity and `vy1` to the y-velocity.